# "The Canaanite, the Hittite, the Amorite, the Prizite, the Jebusite, and the Girgashite,"- What is the Noam Elimelech's source?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, noam-elimelech

The [*Noam Elimelech*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elimelech_of_Lizhensk) writes in the [*Tzeitel Katan (5)*](https://www.sefaria.org/Noam_Elimelech%2C_Introduction%2C_The_Tzetel_Katan.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the following:

(*Source from [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/)*)

(*Partial Quote*)

> כשיתחיל להתעורר בו מידה רעה ח"ו ממידות רעות שהוא רגיל בהם, כגון עקשנות ובושת של גאוה ועצלות ובטלה המביאה לידי שיעמום וכיוצא בהם, יאמר תיכף ומיד בזה הלשון ובכל כחו: "הכנעני החתי האמורי הפריזי החיוי והיבוסי והגרגשי" וינצל
>
> *When one begins to feel temptation from one of his bad traits which he is accustomed to, for example: stubbornness, haughtiness, laziness, idleness that bring one to foolishness and the like, he should say the following verse with all his might: "The Canaanite, the Hittite, the Amorite, the Prizite, the Jebusite, and the Girgashite," and he will be saved*

## My Question

Where does the Noam Elimelech get this idea from?

Comment: I haven't found any earlier sources that say anything remotely like this.  Perhaps he came up with it?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות could be, but I'm sure he got the inspiration from somewhere else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a page from a fairly recently published [translation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1600913792) of the *Tzetel Katan* that has accompanying elucidations as well as prayers and exercises. While this doesn't point to a source per se for the *Noam Elimelech*'s advice, it does shed some light on this method of clearing one's thoughts.

> ***HaCana'ani, HaChiti***
>
> *"You should immediately say, with all of your might: "HaCana'ani, HaChiti..."*
>
> Perhaps the reason for this is as the *Bnei Yisaschar* writes (*Mamarei Chodshei Kislev-Teves, mamar 4, Hallel v'Hodaah*, in the name of the Seer of Lublin), that the seven nations conquered by Yisroel are the seven *sefiros* of the *Sitra Achra*, the Side of Evil (corresponding to the seven *sefiros* of holiness), in the following order: HaCana'ani - *Chesed*; HaChiti - *Gevurah*; HaEmori - *Tiferes*; HaPrizi - *Netzach*;  HaChivi - *Hod*; HaYivusi - *Yesod*; HaGirgoshi - *Malchus*.
>
> <sup>WE CAN FURTHER EXPLAIN THIS, AS FOLLOWS:</sup>
>
> - **Cana'ani** is related to the word *hachna'ah* - "humility". However, this is a sort of meekness that originates from the forces of evil (*kelipos*). It is opposite the ideal state, in which a person's heart is "lifted up in the way of God" (*Divrei HaYamim* 17:6).
> - **Chiti**, from the word *chet* - "fear" (חת). This causes a person to constantly fear that his repentance is not effective.
> - **Emori**, from the word *emor* - "speak". This force does not stop speaking to a person for a minute, trying to subtly entice him and trap him in various types of sin.
> - **Prizi**, from the word "unwalled" (as in "unwalled cities" - ערי הפרזות). This relates to the trait of watonness; that is, when a person does not seek to be bound to his Creator, but imagines that he do whatever he desires.
> - **Chivi**, from the Aramaic word for "snake" (חיוא). It schemes like the primordial Serpent, first trying to seduce a person to sin. Then it bites him repeatedly [with negative feelings of guilt and remorse].
> - **Yivusi**, from the word "to trample" (as in *Tehillim* 60:14). It seeks to trample and annihilate a person from this world and the next.
> - **Girgoshi**, from the word *girushin* - "divorce." It constantly floods a person's mind with foreign thoughts in order to break his connection to God and prayer. In addition, when a person is in the middle of doing a mitzvah, it suddenly wants to kill him, and applies various schemes and evil thoughts to prevent him from completing his deed.
>
> These are the forces of impurity that a person must be wary of. (*Madanei Melech* on *Tzetel Katan*, 5)